# A new entity was found through the relationship that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entit

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

New to doctrine, trying to insert object that has `ManyToOne` rel into database, but getting errors. Writing relevant code below:

Controller:

```
    $oPost    = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:RedditPost')->findOneById(5);
    $oComment = new \AppBundle\Entity\Comments();
    $oComment->setComment('4');
    $oComment->setCreated('2016-11-12');
    $oPost->addComment($oComment);

    $oEm = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $oEm->persist($oPost);
    $oEm->flush(); //  -- getting error here
```

Entity\RedditPost:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Comments", mappedBy="post")
 */
protected $comments;

public function addComment(Comments $comments)
{
    if (!$this->comments->contains($comments)) {
        $comments->setPost($this);
        $this->comments->add($comments);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Entity\Comments:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\RedditPost", inversedBy="comments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $post;

public function setPost(RedditPost $post)
{
    $this->post = $post;

    return $this;
}
```

Full error:

`A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\Entity\RedditPost#comments' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: AppBundle\Entity\Comments@000000005d78d3ae00000000b58ca229. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'AppBundle\Entity\Comments#__toString()' to get a clue.`

What i tried and notes:

- From the error, i tried adding the `,cascade={"persist"}` value to Comments entity, but error didnt change at all
- Tried making 2 persist calls in controller `$oEm->persist($oPost); $oEm->persist($oComment);` - but i get `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` error and cant debug from there.
- I checked my database and all the relations are there, everything seems fine.
- I can insert into RedditPost entity without problems.
- Tried clearing cache.

---

Made new attempt at this, still same results:

```
class Owner {

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
  }

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Child", mappedBy="owner")
   */
  protected $children;

  public function addChild(Child $child)
  {
    if (!$this->children->contains($child)) {
      $child->setOwner($this);
      $this->children->add($child);
    }

    return $this;
  }
}

class Child {

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Owner", inversedBy="children", cascade={"persist"})
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected $owner;

  /**
   * @param mixed $owner
   */
  public function setOwner(Owner $owner)
  {
    $this->owner = $owner;

    return $this;
  }
}

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
       public function indexAction()
       {
              $owner = new Owner();
              $child = new Child();
              $child->setName('test');
              $owner->addChild($child);
              $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
              $em->persist($owner);
              $em->flush();
       }
}
```

---

Current solution is to remove `@ORM\OneToMany` completely, that way i can insert to database without problems.

Comment: im confused with the way you singular and pluralize the addComment(Comments)

Comment: Tried again with new entities on a new project, still same results. Edited my post.

Comment: can you persist/flush the comment entity before persist/flushing the other post entity?

Comment: @Gordon I cant do this `$oEm->persist($oComment); $oEm->flush();`, it gives me the timeout error every time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you shouldn't have `@ORM\OneToMany` from `Post` to `Comment`. In this scenario, you should use `Unidirectional` relationship instead of `Bidirectional`, and handle relationship from `Comment` entity (where foreign key is available). You might want to check this [blog](http://jdjeetonweb.blogspot.in/2014/12/doctrine-mapping-orm-with-database-dal.html) for reference.

So, what you loose when you remove `@ORM\OneToMany` relationship. Literally, nothing. When you want to retrieve list of `Comments` for a single `Post` write a repository and use it.

Comment: I was following a tutorial, and in there the author used bidirectional relationship, but after reading the blog that you linked i think ill use unidirectional (if i understood correctly, i wont need to access a post from a comment object, so thats why unidirectional is better here). Gonna experiment a bit more tho

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem..

I had a timestamp field in my table, which i tried to set like this:

```
 $oComment->setCreated('2016-01-01');
```

This is the reason i could not use `$em->persist($oComment)` (it returned the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error).

Solution was `$oComment->setCreated(new \DateTime('2016-01-01'));`.

This ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error displays nothing and it makes debuging a lot harder.